# Linear independence of a sequence

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm having trouble answering this question that is based on linear independence: Let $V$ be a vector space over a field $F$ and let $W$ and $Y$ be subspaces of $V$ such that $W \cap Y = \{ \vec{0} \}$. Suppose $w⃗_1,w⃗_2,...,w⃗_n$ are linearly independent vectors in $W$ and $\vec{y}_1,\vec{y}_2,...,\vec{y}_m$ are linearly independent vectors in $Y$. Show that $\{ w⃗_1, w⃗_2, . . . , w⃗_n,\vec{y}_1,\vec{y}_2, . . . ,\vec{y}_m \}$ is linearly independent in $V$.

I know that since both $w⃗_1,w⃗_2,...,w⃗_n$ and $\vec{y}_1,\vec{y}_2,...,\vec{y}_m$ are linearly independent, I can say that they both equal $0$ if there exists some $p$ and $q$ such that $pw⃗_1,pw⃗_2,...,pw⃗_n$ and $q\vec{y}_1,q\vec{y}_2,...,q\vec{y}_m$. Does this mean that $\{ w⃗_1, w⃗_2, . . . , w⃗_n,\vec{y}_1,\vec{y}_2, . . . ,\vec{y}_m \}$ is then linearly independent or do I need to prove something else?

Comment: Why don't you try it "by hand"? that is, take a linear combination assume it is 0 and try to prove that all coefficients are null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must have $$\sum_i \alpha_i w_i + \sum_j \beta_j y_j = 0$$ with at least one $\alpha_i \ne 0$ and at least one $\beta_j \ne 0.$

Write this as $w + y = 0$ so that $w=-y \in Y$ (since $y\in Y$ and $Y$ is a subspace).

Contradiction, because $W \cap Y = \{ 0 \} \Rightarrow w \notin Y $.

Answer (score 1):

Take a linear comnbination and assume it is zero:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\vec w_i+\sum_{j=1}^m\mu_j\vec y_j=\vec0$$.

Define $\vec w=\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\vec w_i$ and $\vec y=\sum_{j=1}^m\mu_j\vec y_j$.

It is clear that $\vec w\in W$ and $\vec y\in Y$.

Moreover, by hypothesis, $\vec w=-\vec y\in Y$, so $\vec w\in W\cap Y=\{\vec 0\}$.
So, $\sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_i\vec w_i=\vec 0$ and the linearly independence of the $\vec w_i$'s says that $\lambda_i=0$ for all i.

Analogously, $\vec y=-\vec w\in W$, so $\vec y\in Y\cap W=\{\vec0\}$ and you get also that $\mu_j=0$ for all $j$.

Answer (score 1):

A set of vectors $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}$ is linearly independent if the only solution to the linear equation $\sum_{i} c_i \mathbf x_i = \mathbf 0$ is $c_i = 0$ for all $i$.

For your case, that means we should look at the equation
$$
c_1\mathbf{w}_1 + c_2\mathbf{w}_2 + \ldots + c_n\mathbf{w}_n + c_{n+1}\mathbf{y}_1 + c_{n+2}\mathbf{y}_2 + \ldots + c_{n+m}\mathbf{y}_m = \mathbf{0}.
$$

One thing we can do is to move all of the terms involving $\mathbf{y}_i$ to the right hand side, giving the following equation

$$
c_1\mathbf{w}_1 + c_2\mathbf{w}_2 +\ldots+ c_n\mathbf{w}_n = -c_{n+1}\mathbf{y}_1 - c_{n+2}\mathbf{y}_2 - \ldots - c_{n+m}\mathbf{y}_m.
$$

Now the left hand side is a linear combination of vectors in $W$, and so must lie in $W$, while the right hand side is a linear combination of vectors in $Y$, and so must lie in $Y$.

Can you use what you know about $W$ and $Y$ as well as the sets $\{\mathbf{w}_i\}$ and $\{\mathbf{y}_i\}$ to conclude?